# send popup in desktop application from asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application and on that application i update a sql database ...what i want is that when i update the database from the web application a notification will be sent to any one openening my application or a pop up appears to them on their desktop informing them that the database is updated to check all this will be in an intranet.
I'm using ASP.Net and I'm the admin for all the PCs in the network and the server.
Does anyone knows how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Build a desktop application that *polls the database regularly* or better *write a HTTP/REST service where desktop application poll frequently*.

Comment: I agree with you but what I need is that when a new data is added the web page sends notification to the dektop application and then the desktop application will connect to database to read the updated data only...I don't the connection to be opened automatic every (let's say 10 seconds) and if no new data found then do nothing...I want to notify the desktop application when to read only...got waht i mean ??

Comment: I need the notification to be sent to all pcs in the same moment so i need to notify all the open pcs to connect to the database and read the updated data whenever i add new data

same idea as MSN or Real Player Ads ,etc...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a WCF duplex service your website and your windows clients connect to. With such a service you can use callback methods to inform your windows clients through the service. But be aware that this is normally an intranet and not an internet scenario because such an wcf binding has problems with internet infrastructure (Proxies, Firewalls, ...)

Comment: That's exactly what I want and it is an intranet not internet but I know nothing about WCF so could you please provide me with a link to an article that describes WCF or send me some sample code?

Thanks again for your support Dirk

Comment: Google for wcf callback contracts. The very first item is already a sample for your problem: http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm